# Is Starcraft 2 available for digital download?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is Blizzard offering Starcraft II for digital download (i.e. something like [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/))?

Comment: For a second I thought they were making a Starcraft MMO. :(

Comment: Too bad its not coming to Steam :(

Comment: If you ever see a Blizzard game on Steam it will mean that hell froze over, they're building their very own social network and content distribution platform arround battle.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

via ShackNews "The digital release will come in addition to the boxed retail edition slated to hit stores."

http://www.shacknews.com/onearticle.x/62316

wikipedia translates that article's snippet as: "The game will also be available for digital download from Blizzard shortly after release, if not on the release date"

Blizzard already sells all of their titles Digital Download via their store: http://us.blizzard.com/store/ when sc2 is released it'll likely be available there.

so: Yes, on release date? Maybe.

UPDATE: from official Starcraft 2 Website  http://beta-us.battle.net/sc2/en/

Digital copies go on sale
07/27/2010 10:00 AM PDT

Comment: I brought my digital copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can even download it now:

http://beta-sea.battle.net/en/info/digital-purchase